# How to Iterate through Tables in a DataContext and Test-Read Records?

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext, loops

I am trying to create a `TestMethod` that will enumerate the tables in my data context and attempt to read one record from each table. The goal of the test is to make sure that my .dbml file is in synch with the underlying database. What I have so far:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDataContextTables()
{
    using ( MyDataContext dataContext = new MyDataContext() )
    {
        int count = 0;
        IEnumerable<MetaTable> tableList = dataContext.Mapping.GetTables();

        foreach ( MetaTable table in tableList )
        {
            Debug.Print( "Testing " + table.TableName + "..." );

            // method to restore >= 1 record using LINQ...
            //Object dummy = from t in dataContext.Mapping.GetTables().Skip( count ).Take( 1 ) select t;  <-- wrong (1)
            //Object dummy = from t in dataContext.Mapping.GetTable( table.RowType.GetType() ) select t; <-- also wrong (2)
            //Object dummy = from t in dataContext.Mapping.GetTable( table.RowType.GetType() ).GetType() select t; <-- also wrong (3)

            Debug.Print( "OK\n" );
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

LINQ statement (1) does not appear to read any actual data. LINQ statement (2) gives me the compile-time error “Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'MetaTable'”, and (3) gives the error “Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Type'”. The latter two tell me that I’m referring to a meta-*something* when I should be referring to a *something*.

What I’m looking for is a way to refer to each table in `DataContext` in a LINQ statement and return a row from each record to ensure that the `SELECT` that LINQ generates jibes with the underlying database.

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate table names via LINQ with `select name from sys.tables` and the use SqlQuery (assuming you are using the EF):

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery("select * from " + yourTableName).ToList();
```

Comment: I think this will circumvent the very mechanism I'm trying to test. What I want to verify in this test is that the .dbml file that's part of the project I'm deploying is running against the same version of the database we have in development. Developers have this habit of making changes to the database and failing to record such changes in an agreed upon location, like the deployment plan document. I myself am one of the worst offenders. I want my test function to break if we forget to deploy database changes along with the application.

Comment: Good point. You might try reflecting over your dbml. Why not just build a harness that reads through each table? I realize you will have to code that by hand. Not foolproff but it might be better than nothing.